# How to configure MySQL server to RAD 7.5?

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, webserver, rad

I installed MySQL in my machine, I don't have knowledge of configuring it to RAD 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `data Source Explorer` view. Right click `JDBC Data Source` and select `New...`. First add your driver jar's if there not there already, then fill in your `JDBC` properties.